# How do I find the version of a Windows 8 store/RT app I have installed?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store

I can't seem to find it anywhere, even in the Windows Store and looking up say, the Microsoft "News" app, it does say I have it installed, but does not reveal what version it is.

It would be nice to be able to keep track on what versions you have and compare with what's latest, I'm not sure why this is difficult to find!

Comment: Once you purchase and install an application, Windows ( Windows Store ) will keep track of what updates are release, and should notify you when an application is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open any Windows Store app.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.
3. Click `Permissions`:

   [image]
4. There you have it:

   [image]

Comment: Wow, interesting home for it. Thanks User.. btw what game is that?

Comment: I have changed you to have the accepted answer due to the user-friendliness of your process.

Comment: Actually, even "Settings" -> "About" has it, well on the Music app it does.

Comment: Jetpack Joyride

Answer (score 3):

You can search for them in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes
```

according to [WinSuperSite](http://www.winsupersite.com/blog/supersite-blog-39/windows8/windows-8-registry-140910), you can also find their contracts in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Extensions\ContractId` which contains things like Background Tasks, File, File Picker, Launch, Protocol, Search, and Share.

For more internals of the Windows Runtime, see [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-875T) by Microsoft.

The reason why they don't make this easily available is most likely because they try to mimic the Google Chrome approach where version numbers no longer are that relevant, see also: [Jeff's post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-infinite-version.html)

Comment: I know, but it would be nice to know how many version iterations I am behind though on a product, thanks for the links :)

Comment: You don't need to open the registry. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Powershell :

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name YourAppName | select Version
```