# How do I check the version of a Windows Store Application?

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui, version-control, windows-store-app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the version of a Windows 8 store/RT app I have installed?](https://superuser.com/questions/486639/how-do-i-find-the-version-of-a-windows-8-store-rt-app-i-have-installed)

As any Windows software, Windows Store apps have a release version, but I couldn't find it by looking over the app by itself or from app configs:

[image]

For Desktop Mode apps, it is easily find over "Installed Softwares" on Windows Control Panel:

[image]

**How do I check for the Windows Store App installed versions?**

Comment: Its unlikely there is a similar panel for Modern UI applications.  The version reported has always been up to the developer, so this information can more then likely be found within the given application, I have not been able to find any other way.

Comment: you can check it under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Extensions\ContractId` And see the version. AS under it go to **Windows.Device>PackageID** and you will see the photoviwer's version. A good [link](http://www.winsupersite.com/blog/supersite-blog-39/windows8/windows-8-registry-140910) to dig it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method I found is by using the commandline:

1. Open the Administrative Command Prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>)
2. `cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"`
3. `dir *<app name>*`
4. Version of the program is after the first underscore of the folder name.

E.g. running `dir *Skitch*` on my system gives:

```
2012-10-30  14:18    <DIR>   Evernote.Skitch_2.0.1026.249_neutral__q4d96b2w5wcc2
```

That means *Skitch* on my system has version 2.0.1026.249.

Note that the application folder name might differ from the name presented to the user. Still, you should be able to find your app in this folder easily:

1. Find the folder you think your app is in.
2. Open the `AppxManifest.xml` file inside this folder
3. Search for the `<DisplayName>` property -- it should be equal to the name presented to the user.

You can also run this script in *PowerShell* (remove line breaks first), which will find the appropriate application folder itself:

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsApps> Get-ChildItem -Path . -recurse 
    -include AppxManifest.xml | Select-String -pattern "<your app name>" -List
   | select path
```

Comment: +1 Yes, it is not usual but it works great. Thank you.

Comment: I found Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" | Select-String -pattern "<your app name>" to be enough.